# how adding a fields to relationship Table in pivot table method using laravel

Tags: laravel-4, pivot, eloquent, relationship

I want to design an online store. For each category of productions, we would have its own fields.
Connections between tables of fields and categories are done and displayed in the part of registration of productions.
At the end, the value of each field should be stored that it should contains the related table between table of fields and productions (in addition to/plus/+) the value of that field.
My problem is in this part and I want that this related table has an additional field that I could value it.
In the following figure, the picture of table and my connections are shown, if there is (any problem/ something wrong with it), I would appreciate you to help me.

View Relationship Images :
http://ir-up.ir/uploads/1416568805731.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You'd simply need to add a withPivot when declaring the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
```

Extra attributes in pivot tables are covered in the docs, here - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables